# Marathon how to health check a background worker

Tags: marathon, health-monitoring

I got a standard rails app with 2 process types, the web process and the worker process. both running as tasks on marathon.

Is there a way to define health check to the worker process, the process does not listen on any port, whats recommended here?

Comment: You might find this walkthrough useful: https://github.com/mhausenblas/zdd-lab